# MongoDB: Aggregation - Implementing geo location with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, atlas

Just some clarification with my implementation in mongodb aggregation. I'm having an issue with my implementation. "**$geoNear is only valid as the first stage in an optimized pipeline**"

```
const coordinatesQuery = [
          ...findQuery,
          {
            $match: {
              addressSuburb: { $in: [...suburbList, ...nearbySuburbList] },
            },
          },
          {
            $geoNear: {
              near: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [centerPointOfSearchedSuburbs[0], centerPointOfSearchedSuburbs[1]]
              },
              $maxDistance: 8000,
              distanceField: "distance",
            }
          },
          {
            $project: {
              ...formattedProjection
            }
          },
          {
            $sort: sort
          },
          {
            $limit: take
          },
          {
            $skip: skip
          }
        ];
```

This is what currently have implemented but same issue appear

```
{
            $geoNear: {
              near: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [centerPointOfSearchedSuburbs[0], centerPointOfSearchedSuburbs[1]]
              },
              $maxDistance: 8000,
              distanceField: "distance",
            }
          },
```

Comment: Remove the `$match` stage and put its filter into the `query` argument of the `$geoNear` stage. See [the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/)